# Unzip files from a text file with paths to the archives

Tags: bash, find, zip

Good day to all!
There is a question related to a large number of archives that I collected in one text file with paths to them.
So the Question is, there are any commands to view a list of paths and extract to a certain directory, I used:

```
$ find directoryWherefindZip/ -iname '*.mzp' | unzip -d directoryWhereUnzip/
```

but it doesn't working
Maybe I should add a special path viewer to the file and add it to the unzip loop

Comment: `unzip` doesn’t use standard input this way. According to the `man` page, it won’t even read archive *data* from standard input and it also definitely won’t read plain text lines containing file names. Either use `-exec` to let `find` start `unzip` and give it the file name or pipe the output from `find` into a suitable loop (such as `while IFS= read -r file_name; do unzip -d somedir "$file_name"; done`) and let the loop run `unzip` on each file.

Comment: As a side note, `unzip` handles `.zip` file names in a weird way; only the first file name is a `.zip` file; further arguments are expected to be archive members. But the `.zip` file can be a (strange, limited, built-in) wildcard pattern (interpreted by `unzip`, not by the shell). This implies, among other things, that `find ... -exec ... +` cannot be used and `find ... -exec ... ';'` is needed instead (i.e. a separate invocation for each archive).

Comment: @AndrejPodzimek Thank you for helping with this! I will look in that direction